# work with large numbers and decimals using R

Tags: r

I am currently importing a csv file that contains huge positive numbers separated by decimals in a column
`tb <- read.csv("data.csv",dec = ";")`

```
4,013,054,922
5,208,913,410
5,514,995,512
5,148,498,611
...
```

this data in **R recognizes it as a character** type and I cannot do operations

I have tried with

```r
as.numeric(tb$large)
as.long(tb$large)
as.complex(tb$large)
```

but it returns **rows with NA**

and also try the **gmp library** too, to no avail

I appreciate your help

Comment: `gmp` seems the way to go. What did you try?

Comment: How about the seperator? If it is semicolon, try to add sep=“;” argument inside the function as well.

Comment: I want to try the following `adf.test(tb$large)`,but since it is **char** it will not work

Comment: @maydin I tried it and it still maintains the char format

Comment: did you try `as.numeric(as.character(tb$large)) ` ?

Comment: @MarBlo this generates NA data

Comment: I think your data is an irregular one. I mean, inside the column that you considered as numeric, there exists a character hidden in a single row. So it makes the entire column non numeric.

Comment: @maydin So it seems, I'll try to look at the 1500 data

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub(',','','5,514,995,512'))` evaluates to `5514995512`. The numbers are not so large that something like `gmp` or (easier to use) `Rmpfr` is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```r
d <-  c('4,013,054,922','5,208,913,410',
       '5,514,995,512',
       '5,148,498,611')

class(d)
#> [1] "character"
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_remove_all(d, ','))
#> [1] 4013054922 5208913410 5514995512 5148498611
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: or `as.numeric(gsub(',','',d))` if you want to stay with base R functions